Mover un grafico en Rmarkdown pdf generado por un chunk
una pregunta, como puedo mover un grafico generado por un chunk, el problema es que este grafico esta en la siguiente pagina y me queda casi mitad de pagina en blanco


Sin código, no se podría ver si tienes o no activada la opción adecuada. Ya que r-markdown utiliza latex (por medio de pandoc) para generar el PDF, debes conocer como funcionan las figuras en latex.
En principio, una figura generalmente sigue la sgte estructura:
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{imagen.jpg}
\caption{pié de figura}
\end{figure}

Puedes configurar la posición de la figura, usando alguna/todas las opciones disponibles:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{imagen.jpg}
\caption{pié de figura}
\end{figure}

O utilizar la librería float, y forzar la posición:
\usepackage{float}

...

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{imagen.jpg}
\caption{pié de figura}
\end{figure}

Para que estos cambios se generen en tu documento markdown, debes llamar a esa librería en el preámbulo o añadirla en el YAML:
---
title: ""
date: ""
output: 
  pdf_document :
header-includes:
 \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
---

O incluyendo la librería, configurar todas las figuras del documento usando knitr:
```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H')
```

También lo puedes configurar figura por figura:
```{r, fig.pos = 'H'}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

Lo ideal, es poder configurar todas las opciones de renderizado de tus figuras, utilizando las opciones fig.width, fig.height, fig.fullwidth, etc.
